# Providing YouTube video link (How to Play/Use) button in iOS app or game

Tags: ios, iphone, unity-game-engine, youtube, app-store-connect

Is it legal to make a button for YouTube tutorial link in app?

I have just started publishing games on iOS. It takes hours to upload a game(ipa) on iTunes Connect. It is very frustrating to upload your game again and wait for hours to upload. So definitely I don't want my game to get rejected. I tried google for this question but haven't found any thing related to that.

Is it legal to use same app preview(You Tube Video) that I have made for Google Play, to use in iOS preview video.

Comment: Brief iOS Human Interface Guidelines for "Onboarding" new users: https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/app-architecture/onboarding/ ... It's "legal" to link to external content, but if your users are offline then what do they do? The "preview" video for App Store is a separate issue - if the game UI is identical for both platforms, and you own the rights to the video, why not? If the iOS UI is different, you should create a video showing the iOS UI.

Comment: UI is 100% identical. I used android device to record the preview. Do I have to use Quick Time player to record preview for iOS? Can I use same clip for both?

Comment: Just make sure you prompt the user before opening external links in your app. Also, for what it's worth, a rejection isn't all that bad - they happen a lot. Get used to it ;)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about legal issues / app store review guidelines instead of directly about programming or coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this post](https://blog.placeit.net/difference-app-preview-video-app-demo-video/) for the differences between an "App Preview video" vs "App Demo video"

**App *Preview***: matches device screen sizes; shows only what the user sees on screen; is uploaded via iTunes Connect and appears in the App Store. Apple has specific guidelines to follow.

**App *Demo***: for promotion or tutorial purposes; Can be any content you own & you post it on Youtube or your site or wherever you want.

You could include a link to an external Demo/Tutorial video in your app Settings or About content. However it might be better to include the video directly in the app so users don't have to exit their game to view it, especially if it's a "tutorial" on how to play, or in case they're offline. Better to make that video part of the UI/UX of the game or onboarding process. (If your video is too large to include in the app, it might be too long and complicated anyway).

For "App Preview" details, see Apple's docs on "[Creating Videos for App Previews](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-previews/)".

My comment above was not accurate - you are supposed to upload a separate preview video for each supported iOS device/size so it perfectly fits the device. It's also supposed to ONLY show real content from your app - no actors, ads, or overlays except for explanatory text and graphics indicating user interaction (e.g. displaying a "touch" or gesture).

Your single Android promo video probably will not cover all your needs:

> "Each app preview is device-specific and requires iPhone, iPad, iPod
>   touch, or Apple TV to view and submit. For iOS devices, you can submit
>   a landscape and portrait version of your video. For Apple TV, your
>   video must be in landscape orientation. Your final movie submitted to
>   iTunes Connect must be in M4V, MP4, or MOV file format, less than 500
>   MB, and saved at the following resolutions. For detailed technical
>   specifications and step-by-step instructions on how to submit app
>   previews, read the iTunes Connect Developer Guide."

The iTunes Connect Guide has specific details on [App Preview video properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW10), including resolution, target bit rate, min/max length & files size, etc.

Using Quicktime you can capture the screen of different devices directly.
You can add audio separately in iMovie/Final Cut/some other video editing program.

Looks like you could meet the requirements with 4 different video resolutions:

- 1920 x 1080
- 1334 x 750
- 1200 x 900
- 1600 x 1200

You *could* try to crop & resize your existing video, if it only contains footage of your running app, but that might not work that well.

If your app supports a certain device or resolution, it should have a preview for it, ideally. Since App Previews are an optional feature anyway, you should be able to leave some out & not get rejected. I couldn't find any info about that.

Comment: So it means if I make a preview using iPhone 5 then users with iPhone 5 will be able to see it. Other having different device like iPad and with old or new device than iPhone 5 will not be presented with the preview?

Comment: See the link for video resolutions - it's based on screen size/aspect ratio, not necessarily the device (so a 6-plus, 7-plus, 8-plus should all see the same video; All iPads should see the same video). iPads have a 4:3 aspect ratio; the various phones are 16:9, so at minimum you should probably try 2 versions.